# Optimizing the stored procedure to process 3 million records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have designed a stored procedure usign Sql Server 2005 below to compare 3 million records in each of the Profile and Source Table, and update the Source table with records exist in another table (PROFILE_BC) which will also have about 3 million records.
I am trying to Optimize this code below. Can you suggest any other method ? I just worried that this will take more than about 6 hours to complete. Can we do the same using DTS ? And ideas how this can be done using DTS. Some suggested that there is a component called, Lookup, Fuzzy Lookup that can be used. Any ideas in optimizing the same are welcome.

```
USE Database

GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[ProcName]    Script Date: 11/13/2010 17:15:04 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ProcName] 
AS
BEGIN

 SET NOCOUNT ON;

 DECLARE @not_on_ebc_file_xx## char(2);
    SET @not_on_ebc_file_xx## = 35;

 DECLARE @voters_no varchar(18);
    DECLARE @candidate_id char(10);
 DECLARE @perm_disq_temp char(2);
 DECLARE @voters_no_jms varchar(18);


 DECLARE PROFILES_CURSOR CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD
    FOR SELECT CP.CANDIDATE_ID, CP.VOTERS_NO FROM PROFILE CP INNER JOIN SOURCE SR ON 
 CP.CANDIDATE_ID = SR.CANDIDATE_ID
 WHERE CP.CANDIDATE_ID NOT LIKE 'MA%';


 OPEN PROFILES_CURSOR;
 FETCH NEXT FROM PROFILES_CURSOR 
 INTO @candidate_id, @voters_no;


  WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
  BEGIN

   SELECT @voters_no_jms = VOTERS_NO FROM PROFILE_BC WHERE VOTERS_NO = @voters_no;  
   SELECT @perm_disq_temp = PERM_DISQ FROM SOURCE WHERE CANDIDATE_ID = @candidate_id;

   IF (@voters_no_jms = @voters_no)  -- record exists in jms_temp table/ebc file
   BEGIN   
    IF (@perm_disq_temp = @not_on_ebc_file_xx##)
    BEGIN
       UPDATE SOURCE SET PERM_DISQ = '' WHERE CANDIDATE_ID = @candidate_id;
    END

    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
    IF (@perm_disq_temp = '' OR @perm_disq_temp IS NULL) 
    BEGIN
       UPDATE SOURCE SET PERM_DISQ = @not_on_ebc_file_xx##  WHERE CANDIDATE_ID = @candidate_id;
    END   
    END

   SET @voters_no_jms = '';

   FETCH NEXT FROM PROFILES_CURSOR INTO @candidate_id, @voters_no;

  END 

 CLOSE PROFILES_CURSOR;
 DEALLOCATE PROFILES_CURSOR;

END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should always try to avoid using cursors if you have performance on mind.
Instead of using a cursor you could do this. Try to think in terms of sets when dealing with SQL. I commented out the update part of the query and added a select so that you can see the data.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

DECLARE @not_on_ebc_file_xx## char(2); 
SET @not_on_ebc_file_xx## = 35;

--UPDATE SR
--SET       PERM_DISQ = 
--          CASE WHEN NOT PROFILE_BC.VOTERS_NO IS NULL THEN
--                  CASE WHEN PERM_DISQ.PERM_DISQ = @not_on_ebc_file_xx## THEN '' 
--                      ELSE PERM_DISQ.PERM_DISQ 
--                  END
--              WHEN PERM_DISQ.PERM_DISQ = '' OR PERM_DISQ   IS NULL THEN @not_on_ebc_file_xx##
--              ELSE  PERM_DISQ.PERM_DISQ
--          END
SELECT  CASE WHEN NOT PROFILE_BC.VOTERS_NO IS NULL THEN
                    CASE WHEN PERM_DISQ.PERM_DISQ = @not_on_ebc_file_xx## THEN '' 
                        ELSE PERM_DISQ.PERM_DISQ 
                    END
                WHEN PERM_DISQ.PERM_DISQ = '' OR PERM_DISQ   IS NULL THEN @not_on_ebc_file_xx##
                ELSE  PERM_DISQ.PERM_DISQ
            END AS PERM_DISQ
FROM    PROFILE CP
        INNER JOIN SOURCE SR
            ON CP.CANDIDATE_ID = SR.CANDID_ID
        LEFT JOIN PROFILE_BC
            ON CP.VOTERS_NO = PROFILE_BC.VOTERS_NO
        LEFT JOIN SOURCE PERM_DISQ
            ON CP.CANDIDATE_ID = PERM_DISQ.CANDIDATE_ID
WHERE   CP.CANDIDATE_ID NOT LIKE 'MA%';


ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
```

uncomment the update and set statement and comment out the select statement to update

Comment: The data types here are Perm_Disq is a char(3) and voters_no is a varchar(10). I was wondering if the CASE WHEN PROFILE_BC.VOTERS_NO = PERM_DISQ.PERM_DISQ comparsion is correct. Also would you suggest an error handling code to write to a log file before the Rollback.

Comment: sry it was hard to see your query because it wasn't formatted. I changed  CASE WHEN PROFILE_BC.VOTERS_NO = PERM_DISQ.PERM_DISQ to CASE WHEN NOT PROFILE_BC.VOTERS_NO IS NULL    so if it couldn't find a record that matched the voter_no in the profile_bc table that value would be null

Comment: you could always wrap that up in a try / catch block and raise an error with the raiserror command but I don't see where it would raise an error in this statement unless you have some constraint on the PERM_DISQ column on the Source table.

Comment: the main reason for my post was to show you that what you wanted can be achieved without using cursors. When you put this in the stored proc, you would want to get rid of the begin trans / rollback trans statements unless you wrap those in a   begin trans try .... commit trans catch rollback trans